# Python value problem: SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python, urllib

I'm learning, so go easy on me.

What am I doing wrong here:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.1

import urllib.request

page = urllib.request.urlopen ("http://au.finance.yahoo.com/q?s=AUDUSD=X")
text = page.read().decode("utf8")

where = text.find('Last Trade:</th><td class="yfnc_tabledata1"><big><b><span id="yfs_l10_audusd=x">')

start_of_us_price = where + 80
end_of_us_price = start_of_us_price + 6

us_price = text[start_of_us_price:end_of_us_price]

where = text.find('Trade Time:</th><td class="yfnc_tabledata1"><span id="yfs_t10_audusd=x">')

start_of_trade_time = where + 72
end_of_trade_time = start_of_trade_time + 11

trade_time = text[start_of_trade_time:end_of_trade_time]

print ('The price is $ 'us_price' as of 'trade_time'")
```

Comment: what exactly is the error?
and you have a problem here in the last line - print
i think you mean: print "The price is $", us_price, "as of", trade_time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The last line should be:

```
print ('The price is $ ', us_price, ' as of ', trade_time)
```

Consider this to understand it better:

```
>>> x = 3
>>> print('The value of x is:', 3, 'Yes!')
The value of x is: 3 Yes!
```